# react and redux data from axios not available in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to get my head around React & Redux,

I am fetching some data from an api that I have written, and trying to render that data into one of my components. The data returned is a simple JSON object that looks like this,

```
{
"brief": "No brief given",
"tasks": [
    {
        "_id": "5c74ffc257a059094cf8f3c2",
        "task": "XXX Task 7",
        "project": "5c7458abd2fa91567f4e4f03",
        "date_created": "2019-02-26T08:58:42.260Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
],
"_id": "5c7458abd2fa91567f4e4f03",
"owner": {
    "_id": "5c5af553eea087426cd5f9b9",
    "name": "Test test",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "avatar": "placeholder.jpg",
    "password": "$2a$10$dsGdQZ4APnmAVjbII4vX4u7bCEm0vjxGtHAJ8LijrcBBNTHSn9d5i",
    "created_at": "2019-02-06T14:55:15.321Z",
    "__v": 0
},
"name": "XXX Project 1",
"status": "Pending",
"slug": "XXX-project-1",
"created_at": "2019-02-25T21:05:47.643Z",
"__v": 0
```

}

I retrieve this data via an action in my `componentDidMount()` function in my component like this,

```
       import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getProject } from "../../actions/projectActions";
import Dropdown from "react-dropdown";
import Avatar from "../profile/Avatar";
import ProjectPlaceholder from "../../img/new-project.svg";

import "react-dropdown/style.css";
import "../../css/project.scss";

class Project extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.dispatch(getProject(id));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.project.name)
  }

Project.propTypes = {};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  project: state.project.project,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Project);
```

This is my action,

```
    import axios from "axios";

import { GET_PROJECT, GET_ERRORS } from "./types";

// Set logged in user
export const getProject = slug => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/projects/${slug}`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROJECT,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

and here is my reducer,

```
    import { GET_PROJECT } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {   
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_PROJECT:
            return {
                ...state,
                project: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;   
    } 
}
```

So 1) I cannot work why in my mapToProps function I need to using state.project.project when all that gets returned is JSON object, and 2) why in my render method the console.log logs undefined?

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1.** I cannot work why in my mapStateToProps function I need to using state.project.project when all that gets returned is JSON object

You always need to access it has `state.project.project` because **state** is something which is injected by `connect` and `project` is your **data slice name** in the store, so you need to specify which is the **data slice** you would like to fetch the data from, because you have used **combineReducers** in store.

> **2.** why in my render method the console.log logs **undefined**.

This is because of your `initialState` in your reducer is { } and you are filling this using an **async** call in `componentDidMount`, when render() gets it it's **undefined**.